# How to access variables, from outside a function

Tags: c

I'm writings some C code here. I have a simple error, that is quite confusing. 
I was looking through this aid site: http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-functions-and-global-local-variables. It says, variables declared within a **Main**, could be used within a **function** outside of **Main**. So I have this code here: ***Has been simplified and revised to be less complicated on the eyes.

```
void get_user_input(int grades[], int n) //My function
{ 
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)//Loop to collet grades.
{
printf("Please entera grade between 0 and 100 for student # %i: ", i+1);
 scanf("%d", &grades[i]);

if (grades[i] >= 93)
{
 grades_scale[0]++;
 total_count++;
}
else if (grades[i]<= 92 && grades[i] >= 90)
{
 grades_scale[1]++;
 total_count++;
}
```

Then my main here:

```
int main()
{
int n,i;

printf("How many grades students are in the class?  ");
scanf("%d", &n);

int grades[n];
int grades_scale[11] = {0};
int total_count = 0;

get_user_input(grades,n);
}
```

Within my Main, I have **grade_scale** and **total_count** declared and initialized as **global variables** right? Yet, when I compile and run my program, it sends me an error within my function that states that **total_count and grades_scale haven't been declared**. How do I access my varibables within my **Main**, inside my **Function**? **Ex: total_count, and grades_scale.**

Comment: What's `n < n` has to achieve? Anyway. Your variables are not global. They are local to `main`.

Comment: Oops, I had ment to remove that section. I was going about making an error. To restart the loop if the user inputs some strange or incompatible number. One second please, I'll get rid of it.

Comment: What Eugene said, global variables are placed outside ALL functions, including main.

Comment: Like Eugene said, your variables are local to main. I would suggest reading [this tutorial about scope.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm)

Comment: Thank you, once I read about it, it brought more light to it. I have it working fine now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main() is a function of its own. To be a global variable, it should be initialized outside of any function.

Unless you pass parameters to a function with variables you declared inside main(), then it won't recognize those variables.

Comment: How would I go about this? You mean within main have:

Comment: void get_user_input(int grades[], int n); ?

Comment: You can go the global variable route, just declare your variables in the beginning of the program before you define any functions.

Comment: Thank you, it seemed to work. But, another error arose from it. Like always, this seems do able. Thank you, friend.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example

**Note**

I think it is well worth mentioning, even to a beginner that global variables have their uses but are generally considered bad practice. I won't bother explaining why, use the magic of Google and stackoverflow.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

/* global variables are here 
 * they don't need to be passed to the function */ 
int total_count = 0; 
int grades_scale[11] = {0};

/* your function */ 
void get_user_input(int grades[], int n)
{ 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)//Loop to collet grades.
    {
        printf("Please entera grade between 0 and 100 for student # %i: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &grades[i]);

        if (grades[i] >= 93)
        {
            grades_scale[0]++;
            total_count++;
        }
        else if (grades[i]<= 92 && grades[i] >= 90)
        {
            grades_scale[1]++;
            total_count++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0; 
    printf("How many grades students are in the class?  ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int grades[n] = {0}; 
    get_user_input(grades,n);
}
```

Comment: `int n` should be initialised `int n=0` [See here](http://pastebin.com/raw/CcN2aiMt)

Comment: Oh yes I didn't sanitize his code, merely put the global declarations where they should be!

Comment: Now you got your UP :)